# Django: Saving images uploaded through ImageField

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set up a webapp that accepts image uploads from a user, using ImageField, but I cant seem to figure out how to save the uploaded image. My media folder is empty even though there doesnt seem to be any errors.

Went through a lot of tutorials to no avail. I get the basic concept, create a form, model, set media in settings.py, handle upload in views, and I am getting a working view with a image upload form, but uploading an image does not save.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('embed/', embed, name = 'embed'),
    path('success', success, name = 'success'), 
]


if settings.DEBUG: 
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
                              document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

forms.py

```
class imguploadform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = imgupload
        fields = ['title', 'image']
```

models.py

```
class imgupload(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/images/", default = None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def embed(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = imguploadform(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            newimg = imgupload(title=request.POST['title'], image=request.FILES['image'])
            newimg.save()
            return redirect('success')

    else:
        form = imguploadform()

    return render(request, 'webapp/imgupload.html', {'form' : form})

def success(request):
    return HttpResponse("Successfully uploaded")
```

imgupload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Upload Image</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        {% csrf_token %} 
        {{ form.as_p }} 
        <button type="submit">Upload</button> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Another thing to note, the admin panel does not show the image model

Comment: post the html from where you are calling the form

Comment: edited with html  @Exprator

Comment: What is the __init__() method of your imuploadForm() class? You don't have it. I used init method in a same situation and there I passed imge. If you're problem have not solved yet, tell me to post it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked at my machine whoes os system is ubuntu18 with newest django and pillow

models.py

```
class Imgupload(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def embed(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Imguploadform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("success")
    else:
        form = Imguploadform()
    img = Imgupload.objects.last()
    return render(request, "webapp/imgupload.html", {"form": form, "img": img})


def success(request):
    return HttpResponse("Successfully uploaded")
```

imgupload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload Image</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

    {% if img %}
    Image uploaded latest:
    <img src="{{ img.image.url }}">
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: added html template that I used

Comment: Started new project and copied your code, dont know where I went wrong but it worked